# How to set Jenkins_Home hosted on apache tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, jenkins

I am new to apache tomcat and Jenkins. I have installed Tomcat Apache server and upload Jenkins on it.

So, now Jenkins is there in following directory :

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\jenkins

But when I am trying to execute command as :

```
echo %JENKINS_HOME%
```

it simply returns %JENKINS_HOME%

Please tell me how to set Jenkins home directory. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually I need to change a user permission in Jenkins and I need to give administrative permission to a user. But I did not find any file from which I can do that, so for that I need Jenkins_home directory so that I can find that file.

Comment: its a client requirement to run jenkins on tomcat server, Yes i am able to run jenkins on browser with http://localhost:8080/jenkins

Comment: Once you login as `admin` you can go to `Manage Jenkins -> Manage Users ` then you can edit the `roles and permissions` for a user.

Comment: I dont know how to use jenkins console, and I created a user and gave it all permissions, but now when I am logged into Jenkins with that user than 'Manage Jenkins' option is not available there. Thats the main problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76510/discussion-between-09q71ao534-and-deepak-mr888).

Comment: Go through the discussion once and let me know the status

Answer (score 4):

To change the location of the Jenkins Configuration directory which is running inside the Apache Tomcat server can be done using the below steps:

1. Navigate to the conf directory in the apache-tomcat install path
2. Open the context.xml inside the conf directory and update as below

   `<Context ...>
     <Environment name="JENKINS_HOME" value="/opt/jenikins" type="java.lang.String"/>
   </Context>`

The above code block will change the Jenkins Home to /opt/jenkins.
Replace it whatever you desire.

NOTE: It is important to change the Jenkins Config directory, by default it gets generated in the USER HOME directory where you may not have enough space to hold all the Jenkins Job config data.

Comment: This is apparently no longer effective as of March 2022 with the removal of JNDI support in Jenkins 2.332.1. Seems like setting a system property `-DJENKINS_HOME=/some/path`  when starting Jenkins is now the prescribed method (or also possibly with a regular `JENKINS_HOME` environment variable too).

ref: https://community.jenkins.io/t/jenkins-home-variable-not-read-in-2-332-1-running-in-apache-tomcat-9/1826/2

Answer (score 2):

To set some Windows environment variables, you can customise the following batch:

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\startup.bat
```

Just add the following line at the beginning of the batch:

```
set JENKINS_HOME=C:\YOUR_JENKINS_HOME_PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

In windows,
Open Apache Tomcat Directory,

Locate context.xml under conf folder.

add the following lines

```
<Environment name="JENKINS_HOME" value="C:\Jenkins\JK_HOME" type="java.lang.String"/>
```